# How can i receive aggregate queries for ruby's active record?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, aggregate, camping

Using ruby, camping webframework, activerecord-2.1.1, my db structure is ...

```
create_table :Conf_posts do |t|
  %w{title body username posttime hit passwd}.each do |col|
    t.column :"#{col}", :string
    end
end
```

I want sum of each username's hit

I have the following code.

```
Post.find :all, :select => "username,sum(hit)", :from => "Conf_posts", :group => "username"
```

I received the following results. Only username was returned:

```
[#<Conf::Models::Post username: "\352\260\225\355\230\201">, #<Conf::Models::Post username: "\353\215\225\352\267\234">, #<Conf::Models::Post username: "\353\225\214\355\230\270">, #<Conf::Models::Post username: "\353\263\264\353\236\214">, #<Conf::Models::Post username: "\354\230\201\352\262\275">, #<Conf::Models::Post username: "\354\232\260\353\236\214">, #<Conf::Models::Post username: "\354\235\270\354\204\235">, #<Conf::Models::Post username: "\354\240\225\355\231\224.">, #<Conf::Models::Post username: "\355\230\201\354\235\264">]
```

I can't receive both username and sum of username'hit

Answer (score 5):

```
Post.sum(:hit, :group => :username)
```

should give an array of arrays, something like

```
[ ['user1', 42], ['user2', 109], ...
```

Answer (score 2):

i'stupid :-)

answer is..

Post.sum "hit", :group => "username"

bye~